# Resources for class in different project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I have two project in my solution.
DataAccess - with core models to be shared in other components such as services etc.

Web - net core web app

I need to use localization for data anotions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.0#dataannotations-localization

But I do not know how to set up a resource file in this case, or better to say, where to put it.

The class is placed there

```
DataAccess.Core.Product
```

With property Name and anoted with

```
[Display(Name = "Name")]
```

I use this class in my views and project Web as a viewmodel

```
@model DataAccess.Core.ProductGroup
```

using

```
<label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
```

I have tryed to put resourse file to web project like

```
/Resources/DataAccess/Core/Product.cs.resx
```

localizing controller is working fine for me

```
/Resources/Controllers/ProductController.cs.resx
```

and using

```
IStringLocalizer<ProductGroupsController>
```

Startup config:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddMvc()
 .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
 .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
 .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
 .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();`

var supportedCultures = new[]
{
   new CultureInfo("en-US"),
   new CultureInfo("cs-CZ"),
};
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
   DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
   SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
   SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

Comment: Resources are function of the presentation layer. Until the information is actually *presented* to the end-user, there's no need for localizing it. Therefore, the resources should go in your user-facing application.

Comment: I know, thats why i need to translate Names of attributes. Names are printed to the page using label etc.

Comment: So what's your question?